# Show month filtered by aggregation condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date, aggregation

I have a table that contains customer_id and their apply_date. I want to show all the months in 2016 that the number of customer applying for loans are 30% higher than the monthly average number customers of the year.

```
customer_id   apply_date
-------------------------
1             2016-01-01
2             2016-02-01
3             2016-02-01
4             2016-02-01
5             2016-03-01
6             2016-03-01
7             2016-03-01
8             2016-03-01
9             2016-04-01
10            2016-05-01
11            2017-02-01
12            2017-02-01
13            2017-02-01
```

In this table, in 2016 there are 2 customers who apply every month (average 10 customer divided by 5 month). The term 30% higher than the monthly average is by multiply the average, 2, with 1.3, we have 2.6.

Desired result is I want to show the month that have more than 2.6 customer every month.

By using table above the month in 2016 that match the condition is just 2nd and 5th month.

The table above is just the sample from the data.

I tried using this code

```
select 
    datepart(mm, apply_date) as month, count(*) as cnt
from 
    Leads
where 
    apply_date between '2016-01-01' and '2017-01-01'
group by 
    datepart(mm, apply_date)
```

but I have no idea how to filter the data based on the condition given.

Comment: Could you provide sample data and expect result? How do you calculate number of customer applying for loans are 30%

Comment: @muhnandap, can you please provide whole table structure and some sample data?

Comment: @HasanMahmood thx for the response. I already update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
DECLARE @Leads TABLE
(
    customer_id    INT,
    apply_date DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @Leads(customer_id, apply_date)VALUES(1,'2016-01-01');
INSERT INTO @Leads(customer_id, apply_date)VALUES(2,'2016-02-01');
INSERT INTO @Leads(customer_id, apply_date)VALUES(3,'2016-02-01');
INSERT INTO @Leads(customer_id, apply_date)VALUES(4,'2016-02-01');
INSERT INTO @Leads(customer_id, apply_date)VALUES(5,'2016-03-01');
INSERT INTO @Leads(customer_id, apply_date)VALUES(6,'2016-03-01');
INSERT INTO @Leads(customer_id, apply_date)VALUES(7,'2016-03-01');
INSERT INTO @Leads(customer_id, apply_date)VALUES(8,'2016-03-01');
INSERT INTO @Leads(customer_id, apply_date)VALUES(9,'2016-04-01');
INSERT INTO @Leads(customer_id, apply_date)VALUES(10,'2016-05-01');
INSERT INTO @Leads(customer_id, apply_date)VALUES(11,'2017-02-01');
INSERT INTO @Leads(customer_id, apply_date)VALUES(12,'2017-02-01');
INSERT INTO @Leads(customer_id, apply_date)VALUES(13,'2017-02-01');

--SELECT * FROM @Leads

DECLARE @avgInYear DECIMAL(18,2)

SELECT @avgInYear = SUM(a.NoOfCus)/ CAST(COUNT(a.MonthNo) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT MonthNo = MONTH(apply_date), COUNT(customer_id) NoOfCus FROM @Leads
where apply_date between '2016-Jan-01' and '2017-Dec-01'
GROUP BY MONTH(apply_date) ) AS a

SELECT @avgInYear = @avgInYear * 1.3

select datepart(mm,apply_date) as month, COUNT(customer_id) as cnt
from @Leads
where apply_date between '2016-Jan-01' and '2017-Dec-01'
group by datepart(mm,apply_date)
HAVING CAST(COUNT(customer_id) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) > @avgInYear
```

Comment: @muhnandap if this works, can you please mark 'This answer as useful'?